# Como permitir retorno de acentuação em JSON utilizando PHP?

Tags: php, json

Em anexo a foto do meu retorno JSON

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho seguinte código:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",true);

$array1 = array();
    $contador = 0;
    $estado="online";




if (!$enlace = mysql_connect('meuHost', 'meuUser', 'Minhasenha')) {
    echo '{}';
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db('MinhaBaseDados', $enlace)) {
    echo '{}';
    exit;
}
mysql_set_charset("uft-8");


$sql = 'select distinct(param_curso.curso_designacao) as Universidade, count(candidato_curso.id) as Quantidade from param_curso 
inner join ciclocurso on param_curso.id=ciclocurso.curso_id
inner join candidato_curso on ciclocurso.id=candidato_curso.ciclo_curso_id
group by param_curso.curso_designacao;';

$resultado = mysql_query($sql, $enlace);


if (!$resultado) {
    echo "{}";

}

while ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
   $validacoes =new Cursos_validacoes;
                        $validacoes->universidade = $fila["Universidade"];
                        $validacoes->quantidade = $fila["Quantidade"];

       if($validacoes->universidade==null){
           $validacoes->universidade="vazio";
       }

       $array1[$contador] = $validacoes;
                        $contador = $contador + 1;  



                        }
     echo json_encode($array1);
mysql_close($enlace);






class Cursos_validacoes{    
    public $universidade;
        public $quantidade;

}


?>
```

Comment: qual é o seu problema? não entendi bem o que você quis dizer com retorno de acentuação em JSON, os dados não estão vindo no formato UTF8 do banco de dados ?

Comment: Esse e o problema os dados nao vem no formato UTF8, e nao sei porque.

Comment: Te aconselho utilizar o PDO, essa classe mysql já esta depreciada, mas se for utilizar ela você precisará setar o charset utf, você pode fazer algo como $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);

Comment: Adicionando mysqli_query($minhaconexao, 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); antes da query select se não me engano resolve teu problema.

Comment: Não faz isso! Permita que o retorno seja no formato codificado pela função e pronto. O JSON foi criado para facilitar a troca de dados entre diversas linguagens por meio do Javascript. O formato retornado tem a codificação de caracteres usada no JS, que é hexadecimal. Não faz sentido algum mudar isso.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza o [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) com a constante [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) para codificar literalmente os caracteres em vez de escapa-los.

```
echo json_encode($array1, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Nao comprende a tua sugestao!!!

Comment: Simples, aqui onde tens - `echo json_encode($array1);` - coloca - `echo json_encode($array1, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`.