# Json_econde erro ao parsear caracteres especiais vindos do banco ( usando PDO mysql)

Tags: php, json

Numa tabela do banco existem palavras acentuadas ou com ç .
Ao usar o json_encode no php para enviar o resultado para a view, o json quebra devido o erro no parser.
Qual a melhor maneira de tratar esses caracteres antes de chamar o json_encode?

Exemplo de como retorna do banco. Esses objetos devem ser parseados para json.

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [usuario_nome] => Oliveira Souza
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [usuario_nome] => jão çávão
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [usuario_nome] => joao josjdsojd 
        )
```

Consegui passar os dados da seguinte maneira:

```
$sth = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM v_usuarios  where usuario_ativo = 'S' $condicao order by usuario_nome ASC");
    $sth->execute();
    $datas = array();

    while($data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    array_push($datas,json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));



$retorno =new Response(($datas[0]));
$retorno->headers->set('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
return $retorno;
```

Mas existiria alguma forma melhor?

Comment: Já usou `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120802/php-retorna-json-nulo-quando-tem-acento-no-mysql, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/json-php-e-mysql/155624#155624, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100008/como-permitir-retorno-de-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-json-utilizando-php/100014#100014, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179183/problema-com-json-encode/179186#179186,

Comment: sim...e deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: quando fiz isso o resultado dele foi: Error: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 483 of the JSON data

Comment: Já tentou `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'set names utf8'`?

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, já tive muito desses problemas e não é fácil resolvê-lo, mas tentarei te ajudar.

```
function utf8_converter($array)
{
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
    if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
            $item = utf8_encode($item);
    }
});

return $array;
}
```

Nesse método, você chamando e colocando seu array dentro do parâmetro ele faz um loop no seu array através de cada elemento e converte para UTF-8. Na maioria das vezes pode funcionar, porém há exceções. Espero ter ajudado.