# Filtro não funciona por causa de problema de acentuação do retorno, o que fazer?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-datatables

Estou trabalhando com datatables e php, de forma *server side*.

Venho fazendo filtros personalizados com ele, tudo funcionando ok, com uma salve exceção, as palavras que tem acentuação, não funciona no filtro.

Vamos dizer, que eu seleciono a seguinte empresa: [image: Selecionando o campo com acentuação]

Gabriela e Ana informática LTDA, ele vai dizer que a tabela está vazia.

Não entendendo o erro, reparei que isso só acontecia com palavras que tinham acentuação, então eu olhei como estava o retorno.
[image: Imagem com acentuação zoada]

Claramente, ficou claro o problema, porém não sei soluciona-lo

// código que faz o retorno do json

```
   $data = array();
    while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($rResult) ) {  // preparing an array
        $nestedData=array();


        $nestedData[] = utf8_encode($row["razao_social"]);
        $nestedData[] = utf8_encode($row["organization_name"]);
        $nestedData[] = $row["organization_type"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["edition"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["licensed_version"];
        $nestedData[] = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row["issued_date"]));
        $nestedData[] = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row["support_expiry_date"]));
        $nestedData[] = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row["updates_expiry_date"]));
        $nestedData[] = $row["advanced_clients_licensed"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["users_licensed"];
        $nestedData[] = "<a href='detail-license.php?id=".$row['id_license']."'><button class='btn btn-success'><i class='fa fa-list'></i> Detalhes</button></a>";
        $nestedData[] = "<a href='download.php?id=".$row['id_license']."'><button class='btn btn-success'><i class='fa fa-download'></i> Download</button></a>";
        $data[] = $nestedData;
    }

    $output = array(
        "draw" => intval($_GET['draw']),
        "recordsTotal" => $iTotal,
        "recordsFiltered" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "data" => $data
    );

    echo json_encode( $output );
```

// código que envia para o php fazer o tratamento dos dados

```
$('#btnFiltrar').on( 'click', function () {
    var dados = new Array();
    $('#frmReportLicense').find(":text:visible,:checkbox:checked,select:visible,input:checked").each(function(v) {
        dados[v] = $(this).val();
    });

    dataTable.columns().search(dados).draw();
    console.log(dados);
});
```

**Atualização**

Na minha saída coloquei:

```
$output = array(
    "draw" => intval($_GET['draw']),
    "recordsTotal" => $iTotal,
    "recordsFiltered" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "data" => $data
);
echo json_encode( $output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

Ele até começou a retornar o valor certo, só que ele não filtra.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possíveis relacionadas, se não "quadriplicada": https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65867/acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-json, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%C3%BAvida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193059/json-em-php-com-campos-existentes-imprimindo-como-null-como-resolver e  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100008/como-permitir-retorno-de-acentuação-em-json-utilizando-php.

Answer (score 1):

Não sou muito experiente nesta área mas talvez dar um *encodeURIComponent* no valor possa resolver o problema.
Ficando então:

```
dados[v] = encodeURIComponent($(this).val());
```

Também estava com problemas com caracteres especiais e essa função resolveu o problema.
Espero que resolva seu problema :D

Comment: valeu pela dica, vou testar assim que terminar minha hora do almoço

Comment: cara, não deu certo